# How can I use a JSON based drop-down to filter an xml source?

Tags: html, json, ajax, knockout.js

I am setting up a web page which currently pulls through data from an xml source, using Ajax. What i'm now attempting to do is filter this selection using JSON. I have been able to set up a drop-down list containing the relevant selections, how my issue is in then applying this to the dataset.

I'm fairly new to JSON so apologies is this has already been answered, but i can't seem to find a relevant question that has been answered.

So far i have my drop down:

```
            <p>
                Filter Name:
            <select data-bind="options: filters, value: filter"></select>
            </p>
```

The body of my table:

```
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: { data:records, afterRender:highlight }">            
                <tr class="table-row" data-bind="click: $root.selectThing ">
                    <td data-bind="text: data"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: data"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: data"></td>
                </tr>            
            </tbody>
```

Below is my JSON script, i have set up my filters however I'm lost in trying to apply the Filter Name to the variable "dataFromServer".

Any feedback with this would be greatly appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var json;

    function typeModel() {

        var self = this;

        self.records = ko.observableArray();
        self.CurrentDisplayThing = ko.observableArray();

        self.filters = ko.observableArray(['Filter1', 'Filter2']);
        self.filter = ko.observable(['']); 

        self.selectThing = function(item) {

                                            self.CurrentDisplayThing.removeAll();
                                            self.CurrentDisplayThing.push(item);
                                            self.filteredItems = ko.computed(function() {
                                                var filter = self.filter();
                                                      if (!filter || filter == "None") {
                                                        return self.records();
                                                      } else {
                                                        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.records(), function(i) {
                                                          return i.Type == filter;
                                                        });
                                                      }
                                                    });
        };

       $.ajax({
        type: "GET" ,
        url: "xml/aag_sd.xml" ,
        dataType: "xml" ,
        success: function(xml) {

            json = xml2json($(xml)[0],"");

             var dataFromServer = ko.utils.parseJson(json);
            // self.records(dataFromServer.AAG.AtAGlance);
            self.CurrentDisplayThing.removeAll();
            self.CurrentDisplayThing.push((self.records()[0]));
            self.filteredItems = ko.computed(function() {
            var filter = self.filter();
              if (!filter || filter == "None") {
                return self.records();
               } else {
               return ko.utils.arrayFilter(
                  self.records(dataFromServer.AAG.AtAGlance), 
                         function(i) {
                          return i.Type == filter;
                        });
                      }
                    });
}

    });


    }
    ko.applyBindings(new typeModel());


});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the below function in the wrong section:

```
        self.filteredItems = ko.computed(function() {
            var filter = self.filter();
                  if (!filter || filter == "None") {
                    return self.records();
                  } else {
                    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.records(), function(i) {
                      return i.type == filter;
                    });
                  }
                });
```

With the resulting code looking like this:

```
    function wardModel() {

        var self = this;

        self.records = ko.observableArray();
        self.CurrentDisplayThing = ko.observableArray();

        self.filters = ko.observableArray(['Filter1', 'Filter2']);
        self.filter = ko.observable(['']); 

        self.filteredItems = ko.computed(function() {
            var filter = self.filter();
                  if (!filter || filter == "None") {
                    return self.records();
                  } else {
                    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.records(), function(i) {
                      return i.type == filter;
                    });
                  }
                });

        self.selectThing = function(item) {

                                            self.CurrentDisplayThing.removeAll();
                                            self.CurrentDisplayThing.push(item);

        };

       $.ajax({
        type: "GET" ,
        url: "xml/aag_sd.xml" ,
        dataType: "xml" ,
        success: function(xml) {

            json = xml2json($(xml)[0],"");

             var dataFromServer = ko.utils.parseJson(json);
            self.records(dataFromServer.AAG.AtAGlance);
            self.CurrentDisplayThing.removeAll();
            self.CurrentDisplayThing.push((self.records()[0]));
```

And...

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: { data:filteredItems, afterRender:highlight }">
```